# ^[!-//-~] in regex

Tags: python, regex

In  python 2.7  what  does this  regex match ?

```
^[!-//-~]
```

Is there a good source as http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html doesn't cover it.

Comment: The documentation *does* cover it.

Comment: Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-', for example [a-z] will match any lowercase ASCII letter, [0-5][0-9] will match all the two-digits numbers from 00 to 59, and [0-9A-Fa-f] will match any hexadecimal digit. If - is escaped (e.g. [a\-z]) or if it’s placed as the first or last character (e.g. [a-]), it will match a literal '-'.

Answer (score 7):

- The `^` is the 'start of string' anchor, the expression only matches at the start.
- The `[...]` block is a character class, the contained characters are treated as a set. One of these at the start of the line is enough to constitute a match.

  The dashes in the class constitute a range, running from `!` through to `/` and from `/` through to `~`; the end of the first range overlaps the start of the second, so `[!-~]` is enough.

  Between the `!` and `~` lie all printable [ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), apart from the space character. The `/` slash lies just before the digits; it looks as if someone forgot to merge the two sets after some refactoring.

So any of the following lines would match:

```
!whatever
"don't care
~still doesn't matter what follows
/It's the first character that counts.
ABut almost anything printable in the ASCII range matches
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `[!-~]` (or is that a python-specific escape)?

Comment: @Bergi: Ah, no, of course, it's a series. :-P

Comment: `!-/` and `/-~` are two ranges. Actually, it's the entire ASCII set.

Comment: The only printable character not in `!-~` is the space :)

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Was just editing that in. :-)